# <Loaction> in web.config doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I set a `FormAuthentication` to my website.

I want to allow access to the Login page

1. `?` is anonymous and `*` is everyone. What is the difference?
2. I added `<location>` to `web.config`. Does the order there matter?

   ```
   <configuration>
     <configSections>
       <section name="hibernate-configuration"  
                type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
       <section name="log4net" 
                type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
     </configSections>
     <appSettings>
       <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
       <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
       <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
     </appSettings>
     <location path="~/Authentication.htm">
       <system.web>
         <authorization>
           <deny users="*" />
         </authorization>
       </system.web>
     </location>
     <location path="~/Resources">
       <system.web>
         <authorization>
           <deny users="*" />
         </authorization>
       </system.web>
     </location>
     <location path="~/js">
       <system.web>
         <authorization>
           <deny users="*" />
         </authorization>
       </system.web>
     </location>
     <location path="~/Images">
       <system.web>
         <authorization>
           <deny users="*" />
         </authorization>
       </system.web>
     </location>
     <location path="~/Controllers">
       <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="*" />
         </authorization>
       </system.web>
     </location>
     <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
         <assemblies>
           .....
         </assemblies>
       </compilation>
       <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms name="Login" loginUrl="~/Authentication.htm"
                protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
       </authentication>
       <authorization>
          <deny users ="?" />
          <allow users = "*" />
       </authorization>
   ```

Why do I still get authentication errors for the path I have added to the `<location>`?

> Authentication.htm?ReturnUrl=%2fResources%2fScripts%2fjquery-1.7.1.min.js:1Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> Authentication.htm?ReturnUrl=%2fjs%2fCommon.js:1Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token <
>
> Authentication.htm?ReturnUrl=%2fjs%2fAuthentication.js:1Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Where did you add the location tag? The order in and structure of that file definitely matters.

Comment: I was missing the qoutations in my post so my webconfig became transparent. revised

Comment: @EladBenda: yeah, it's a bit messy - if you happen to have code or config inside a numbered (or bulleted) list, you need to intend the code by 8 (not 4) characters to make it appear formatted....

Comment: @marc_s, any idea how to approach my problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. The difference between ? (anonymous) and * (everyone) is that * includes all anonymous and other users, while ? only include users that aren't logged on yet.

Comment: Thanks. can you help with the 2nd?